# trying to examine a var in LLDB in XCODE. can you execute functions at all, or just variable data?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, lldb

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH3-SW1 is the site i noticed, but i was having issues with `Json::Value` being human readable, so i watch to call "toString" on it.

It doesn't seem to enjoy that though when trying to do:  `p someVar.toString()`

Does anyone know how i might get through this?

Comment: You are using the command correctly.  You'll have to tell us what went wrong for us to help further.

Comment: I think my issue is that `toString()` wasnt the correct command.  I had to look up the class Json::Value to see whats going on, and what the command is and it ended up being:  `toStyledString()`